# Should I use the largest string data type when creating a user defined function which operates on strings?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

When creating a user defined function is it "bad" to just automatically use the largest string possible?

For example, given the following UDF, I've used `nvarchar(max)` for my input string, where I know perfectly well that the function currently isn't going to need to accept `nvarchar(max)` and maybe I'm just forward thinking too much, but I supposed that there would always be the possibility that maybe an `nvarchar(max)` would be passed to this function.

By doing something "bad" I'm wondering that by declaring that this function could possibly receive and actual `nvarchar(max)` am I doing anything to possibly cripple performance?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsMasNull] (@value nvarchar(max)) 
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
        CASE 
            WHEN @value IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN CHARINDEX(char(0), @value) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVARCHAR(MAX) will affect performance if its a database column. As a parameter to a stored procedure it should make no difference. If at all there is a degraded performance its because of the sheer size of the data and not the datatype.